# Android - reading a file without repeated user consent

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing a small medical app as means of trying out my newly learned Android skills. I want to be able to read a text file from a specific folder on the device (not the SD card) where the user can put some medical information (when the app starts upp) without having the user need to pick the file destination, but I am not sure how to implement it. I may also want to write to the file.

The file may change frequently. The truth is, I need to read from a directory with a variable number of subdirectories, each with 4 files in them. It is those files I need to read and then display, but for the sake of simplicity I limited the question to just reading the file. It seems like this would be a file which would be in "Internal Storage/Android/data/com.me.myapp/medical_information", but I am not sure how convenient that would be for the user to constantly have to find the app among all of the app folders, and then navigate to the folder. Where would be the best place to put this folder/file, and how would go about writing/reading from it?

It is preferrable that answers be written in Kotlin, but not essential.

Comment: You can place as many files and folders in getExternalFilesDir() as you want. No user interaction. No permissions needed.

Comment: It is unclear how the user would navigate to that folder. Using your app?

Comment: But that means writing to an SD card, no?

Comment: No, using the phone native file explorer.

Comment: No. Not to a removable micro sd card but to build in memory.

Comment: Where would the files go? Where could I put them? What would be the path?

Comment: That i told you in my first comment. Use getExternalFilesDir(). The path would be getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().